# Zeek is not storing files, even after script was loaded. What am I missing?

Tags: bro, zeek

I'm trying to configure Zeek in order to store files (every file) on disc, but without any success.
OS I'm using: Debian 10.

What I did so far:

- I've installed this module: https://github.com/hosom/file-extraction (even after following this site https://www.ericooi.com/zeekurity-zen-part-vi-zeek-file-analysis-framework, I couldn't put it to work).
- I've loaded frameworks/files/extract-all-files script.

I can see the scripts are loaded, after checking loaded_scripts.log

I'm a beginner on Zeek, and I'd like to learn how to enable zeek to save files (that is traversing the network) and store on disk. The only sort of files that is being stored: HTTP and SSL.

I'm sure I'm making many mistakes, but I'm not able to find the correct way.

---

EDIT

Zeek version I'm using: zeek version 4.1.0-dev.545.

I'm processing traffic. I haven't tried anything with pcap, but I'll try what you've suggested with "zeek -r the.pcap policy/scripts/frameworks/files/extract-all-files.zeek".

On Zeek server, I've installed (in order to test) a FTP and a HTTP server. At html folder, I created a pdf file (so I can download it later).
I've put two files (a pdf and a plain text file), and I downloaded (using a browser on another computer in the local network) that pdf file.
As a result, I can see (looking at ftp.log and http.log) all the files that I mentioned, but those files aren't stored on disc. My doubt is: should they be stored by Zeek?

Comment: What version of Zeek are you using, Paulo, and how are you running Zeek? Are you processing live traffic or a pcap? If a pcap, check that the packets are captured fully and have intact checksums (let me know if you need help with those). Let's start with just loading `extract-all-files.zeek`, because it should extract files. If you have a pcap, does `zeek -r the.pcap policy/scripts/frameworks/files/extract-all-files.zeek` work?

Comment: Actually, I missed the fact that you're saying HTTP and SSL (certs, presumably) are getting extracted. That might well be all that's extractable in your traffic — what else are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry about that: I'll edit my answer to add these information.

Comment: I've done "zeek -r the.pcap policy/scripts/frameworks/files/extract-all-files.zeek" with a slight change: as I got the message that my file has invalid tcp checksums, I run the command with -C option and the files were stored in extract_files folder, that is, it worked.

Comment: After this test, I run zeek -C -i eth0 policy/frameworks/files/extract-all-files.zeek, and those files were stored. Now my I conclude the initial problem was the invalid tcp checksums?

Comment: @Christian I've add the line redef ignore_checksums = T; on local.zeek, and run zeekctl deploy and it started storing files. Do you think ignoring checksums is a problem? For me, I intend to use zeek with yara in order to look for virus and stuff like that.

Comment: One more thing: since I see you solved my problem, I suggest you wrote your comments as an answer, in order to accept it.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it to work! That's a common gotcha. I'll write it up below. Thanks Paulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common problem when running traffic through Zeek is that packets may have invalid checksums. Zeek by default skips such packets, so the net result is missing logs/files/artifacts that the user expects to be there. Often those invalid checksums are caused by checksum offloading, where the packet capture process grabs transmitted packets before the NIC had a chance to fix the checksums.

Zeek normally warns when it encounters invalid checksums -- look for the something resembling the following on stderr, or in reporter.log:

> Your trace file likely has invalid TCP checksums, most likely from NIC checksum offloading.  By default, packets with invalid checksums are discarded by Zeek unless using the -C command-line option or toggling the 'ignore_checksums' variable.

(This is from [find-checksum-offloading.zeek](https://github.com/zeek/zeek/blob/master/scripts/base/misc/find-checksum-offloading.zeek), which is included in Zeek's default configuration.)

You have many options here. You can:

- run Zeek with `-C`, as per the above
- say `redef ignore_checksums=T;` in a script (usually local.zeek)
- add the redef at the command line: `zeek -r the.pcap ... ignore_checksums=T`
- fix the checksums in the pcap, e.g. with `tcprewrite -C -i input.pcap -o fixed.pcap` (`tcprewrite` ships with tcpreplay) -- this is best if others will consume your pcap too.